# How to Continuously receive DatagramPackets in Java

Tags: java, udp, chat, packet, datagram

I have written a client and server that are currently in an endless loop, that allow one message at a time to be sent and received. I need it to be able to continuously send/receive messages rather than be limited to one at a time.

Any idea on how I may go about this?

I am new to threads and not entirely sure how they work but i was thinking maybe a thread?

#### Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientChat {

    DatagramSocket Socket;

    public ClientChat(){

    }

    public void createAndListenSocket() throws SocketException, IOException{

        while(true){
            Socket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Type your message:");
            BufferedReader message = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            byte[] incomingData = new byte[256];
            String sentence = message.readLine();//"Testing from client";
            byte[] data = sentence.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, 9876);
            Socket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("Client: " + sentence);
            DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
            Socket.receive(incomingPacket);
            String reply = new String(incomingPacket.getData());
            System.out.println("Server: " + reply);
            //Socket.close();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        ClientChat client = new ClientChat();
        client.createAndListenSocket();
    }
}
```

#### Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerClient {

    public void run() throws Exception{

        DatagramSocket Server = new DatagramSocket(9876);

        while(true){        
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];   
            DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            Server.receive(incomingPacket);
            String message = new String(incomingPacket.getData());
            System.out.println("Client: " + message);
            System.out.print("Server: ");
            BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String reply = response.readLine();
            InetAddress IPAddress = incomingPacket.getAddress();
            int port = incomingPacket.getPort();
            byte[] data = reply.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket replyPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, port);
            Server.send(replyPacket); 


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerClient Server = new ServerClient();
        Server.run();
    }        
}
```

Comment: You're doing exactly that already. The `DatagramSocket` should be created outside the loop. Otherwise it is difficult to tell what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You should use two threads - one for sending and one for receiving. You will also need two buffers to store the data while it's waiting to be send or processed after receiving. Most likely, you'll want FIFO buffers (a simple two-sided synchronized queue). Then, your main thread can only deal with reading/writing data to the queue, and the sending/receiving threads will take care of the rest in the background.

- The sending thread should try to read from sending queue in a loop. The read operation on queue should block (pause the thread) until data is available.
- The receiving thread should run in a loop to read a datagram from network and store it into a "received" queue. Reading datagram from network will block, while storing into a queue will return immediately unless the queue is full.
- When the program is finished, you have to somehow "break" the threads from their loop. For example, you can set "shouldExit" boolean to true in your main thread, and check it in your send/receive threads. If you don't care, you can also set threads to daemon mode or just call System.exit().

Size your queues appropriately. If too small, messages will get lost and/or threads will be blocked a lot of time. If too large, you will waste memory. For example, estimate (or observe) the average and maximum number of messages in a queue, and add a safety margin.

Comment: Thank you so much this detailed response is definitely the kind of answer i was looking for! I am not to familiar with threads as i've just really started working in the programing space at school so im going to have to research them to understand how to write, and implement them but i think once i understand that your answer gives me a great place to get a concept to follow!

Comment: Supplementary question. Can one declare ```DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);``` above the loop so as to reuse the same DatagramPacket object instead of creating a new object with each iteration?